# JavaScript: "identifier has already been declared

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, sass

I'm following a tutorial and have exactly what the instructor has. But my program won't compile:

`SyntaxError: /Users/at/Notes App/my-app/src/components/Sidenavbar/Sidenavbar.js: Identifier 'Sidenavbar' has already been declared (5:4)`

```
import Sidenavbar from './components/Sidenavbar/Sidenavbar';
import './Clone.scss';

const Sidenavbar = () => {
    return (
        <div className="Clone">
            <h1> hi </h1>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Sidenavbar;
```

I'm not really sure what the problem is since I've copied everything line by line but the instructor's program runs.

I also tried changing the name of the variable 'const Sidenavbar' and more errors shows uo.

Comment: it's defined in `import Sidenavbar` ... so `let Sidenavbar =` is a re-declaration - I think the `let Sidenavbar = ....` etc is what should be in the file ... `./components/Sidenavbar/Sidenavbar` and `import Sidenavbar ...` etc is how you use it - you've probably misunderstood your instructor, or your instructor misunderstands javascript - I mean, how do you know the instructors code works? because he says it does? probably not (definitely not)

Comment: I omitted let now, but I get a different error: ./src/components/Sidenavbar/Sidenavbar.js
Module not found: Can't resolve './components/Sidenavbar/Sidenavbar' in '/Users/at/Notes App/my-app/src/components/Sidenavbar'

Comment: have you created that file? if not, you need to

Answer (score 1):

You are already performing an `import` of `Sidenavbar` in this line

```
import Sidenavbar from './components/Sidenavbar/Sidenavbar';
```

and few line bellow you try to define a constant with the same name. that's the reason you have that error.

```
const Sidenavbar = () => {
```

You can solve that by renaming the constant of by aliasing the imported component like this

```
import {default as SideNavigationBar } from './components/Sidenavbar/Sidenavbar';
```